# Heron Iteration with NestWhileList

Tags: numerics

I am trying to write a procedure which calculates the square root of a given number with a given accuracy `epsilon` (Heron iteration). The procedure should output the calculated square root and the number of steps needed to calculate it.

```
heron[xn_,epsilon_] := (liste =N[NestWhileList[ 1 + (xn - 1)/(1 + #) &,
                        xn, Abs [#1 - #2] >= epsilon &, 2]];
                        List[Last[liste], Length[liste]])
```

It almost works, but if I set `epsilon` to $10^{-4}$ it doesn't work; with all other values for `epsilon` it does work. I am new to *Mathematica* and I am struggling with debugging this.  I can't find the problem with `epsilon` being equal to $10^{-4}$. Hope anyone can help me with this or point me in the right direction.

Comment: The code that you posted has incorrect syntax and is missing something. Please edit your question to include working code.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm works fine for `epsilon == 10^-4`

```
Clear[heron]

heron[xn_, 
  epsilon_] := (liste = 
   N[NestWhileList[1 + (xn - 1)/(1 + #) &, xn, Abs[#1 - #2] >= epsilon &, 2]];
   List[Last[liste], Length[liste]])

Abs[Sqrt[2] - heron[2, 10^-4][[1]]]

(*  0.000012379  *)

heron[2, 10^-#] & /@ Range[2, 10]

(*  {{1.41463, 5}, {1.41414, 6}, {1.41423, 7}, {1.41421, 9}, {1.41421, 
  10}, {1.41421, 11}, {1.41421, 13}, {1.41421, 14}, {1.41421, 15}}  *)
```

I recommend using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to avoid putting `liste` into the global namespace. With some other minor changes:

```
Clear[heron]

heron[xn_, epsilon_?Positive] :=
 Module[{liste},
  liste = NestWhileList[1. + (xn - 1)/(1 + #) &, xn, 
    Abs[#1 - #2] >= epsilon &, 2]; 
  {Last@liste, Length@liste}]

heron[2, 10^-#] & /@ Range[2, 10]

(*  {{1.41463, 5}, {1.41414, 6}, {1.41423, 7}, {1.41421, 9}, {1.41421, 
  10}, {1.41421, 11}, {1.41421, 13}, {1.41421, 14}, {1.41421, 15}}  *)
```

However, for faster convergence

```
Clear[heron]

heron[xn_, epsilon_?Positive] :=
 Module[{liste},
  liste = NestWhileList[(# + xn/#)/2 &, 1.,
    (Abs[#1 - #2] >= epsilon &), 2];
  {Last@liste, Length@liste}]

heron[2, 10^-#] & /@ Range[2, 10]

(*  {{1.41422, 4}, {1.41421, 5}, {1.41421, 5}, {1.41421, 5}, {1.41421, 
  6}, {1.41421, 6}, {1.41421, 6}, {1.41421, 6}, {1.41421, 6}}  *)
```

An alternative to using `NestWhileList` would be to use [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html)

Comment: Thx a lot for the additional Info. Thats strange i tried with 10^-4 it works but if i write 0.0001 it doesnt work.

Comment: @Viking - `0.0001` works for me. I am using version 11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: Strange, im on 10.4 Windows x64. For now writing 10^-4 is okay maybe will get to the bottom of this later.Thx a lot Bob

Comment: @Viking - it also works with `0.0001` in version 10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)